# How to add values between two given dates

Tags: php, date, loops, multidimensional-array

How can I add values between two given dates? I have an array that contains date dd.mm.yyyy format and it's corresponding value.

The array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => 01.08.2014
[1] => 600
)

[1] => Array
(
[0] => 02.08.2014
[1] => 500
)

[2] => Array
(
[0] => 03.08.2014
[1] => 700
)

[3] => Array
(
[0] => 04.08.2014
[1] => 600
)

[4] => Array
(
[0] => 05.08.2014
[1] => 600
)

[5] => Array
(
[0] => 06.08.2014
[1] => 600
)

)
```

Example: 01.08.2014 to 03.08.2014 = 1800.
How can I do that using loops?
I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
$row_length = count($data);
                $sum = 0;
                for ($row = 0; $row < $row_length; $row++) {
                    $ax = $data[$row][1];
                    if ($data[$row][0] == $date1) {
                        $sum =  $ax + $sum;
                        echo $test;
                        if ($data[$row][0] == $date2) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would benefit from finding a better format for this data.

Having said that, with your current array I think this will do the trick and if you wrap this in a function you could pass in start and end:-

```
$test = array();
$test[0] = array('01.08.2014', 300);
$test[1] = array('02.08.2014', 400);
$test[2] = array('03.08.2014', 800);
$test[3] = array('04.08.2014', 400);
$test[4] = array('05.08.2014', 900);
$test[5] = array('06.08.2014', 100);


$start = new DateTime('01.08.2014');
$end = new DateTime('03.08.2014');
$total = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($test); $i++) {
    $date = new DateTime($test[$i][0]);
    if ($date >= $start && $date <= $end) {
        $total += $test[$i][1];
    }
}
echo $total . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
row_length = count($data);
                $sum = 0;
                for ($row = 0; $row < $row_length; $row++) {
                    $ax = $data[$row][1];
                    if ($data[$row][0] == $date1 || $sum != 0) {
                        $sum =  $ax + $sum;
                    }
                        if ($data[$row][0] == $date2) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```